# How to start Docker container only after another container is exited

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

Let's suppose I have 2 containers: `composer` and `php`, which share the same code base, i.e. the same volume. And I want to manage them with a single docker-compose command like `docker-compose up`.

So the question is How can I start these containers one by one, not at the same time? I mean, start my `php` container only after `composer` one is exited, i.e. `composer` container should install all vendors for my `php` container and exit, then and only then `php` container should start a built-in PHP web server with already installed vendors.

P.S. Now I get the behavior that both containers start at the same time. So my `php` container is trying to start web server without vendors, while `composer` container is trying to install these vendors.

Is there a good solution for this case?

Comment: you can write a script, checking what `docker ps --filter "name=composer"`  or the shorter `docker ps -q --filter "name=composer"`returns. If you do not get a string of numbers and letters (for the last one), it means it exited. You can also listen to `docker events` such as `docker events --filter 'container=7805c1d35632'` and look for "container die" or such. I think your best bet is something like `docker events --filter 'container=7805c1d35632' --filter 'event=stop'`  check the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/

Comment: Hey @user2915097 , thanks a lot for this information. It really makes sense, however, the only problem I see that I should run this filtering script on my host machine, not inside the container. But can I do the similar check inside a container? Then I can run an infinite loop which checks every 2 seconds if `composer` container has died and then will finish the infinite loop and run built-in web server. Do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: Yes you can, you need, when you launch your container, to mount the docker socket, like `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock...` Now inside your container, you can use the docker commands

Comment: you can also use signals, see http://blog.dixo.net/2015/02/sending-signals-from-one-docker-container-to-another/ I do not like the idea of checking every 2 seconds, I think there should be better options

Comment: See also the idea of AmanicA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y and wait-for-it https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thank you very much for these links, I think I need some time to handle them )

Comment: How about proper CI pipeline in Jenkins?

Comment: sample docker-compose.yml:
  services:
      container_a:
         ...
      container_b:
           depends_on:
             container_b:
              condition: service_completed_successfully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are couple of things can help you;

- depends_on: it does not wait for another service to finish, it only waits until the other services starts. see: [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on)
- health_check: it does not start the service until the command returns success. see: [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck)
- create a shell script to order of initialisation of your containers/services. see: [startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)